# How to retrieve img Url from Firebase storage into Firebase database on child value using React Native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

This is my structure data on Firebase.

[image: this is my structure data on firebase]

I want get imageUrl from Firebase Storage into child in "barang".

Comment: What's the problem? You'll find that you're much more likely to get help on Stack Overflow if you [create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are asking about.